# How to register keymaps for all editor types?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I want to write an addon, which enables you to switch quickly, via a pie menu, between the editor types. (e.g. Node Editor, 3D View, Graph Editor, etc...)
To get my shortcut working, I need to register the same keymap for every space or editor type.

(e.g.:`keymap_items.new("wm.call_menu_pie", type = "E",alt=True, value = "PRESS")`)

Right now I got it working with only one editor type:

`keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name = "Node Editor", space_type = "NODE_EDITOR")`

I know, I could simply register my keymap for every single editor type with a loop, but I am sure there is a more convenient and beatiful way to accomplish my objective.

( Maybe something like `space_type = "WINDOW"?`)

PS: My current registration code looks like this:

```
addon_keymaps = []
def register_keymaps():
    global addon_keymaps
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name = "Node Editor", space_type = "NODE_EDITOR")
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new("wm.call_menu_pie", type = "E",alt=True, value = "PRESS")
    kmi.properties.name = "view3d.switcher"
    addon_keymaps.append(km)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I randomly discovered the answer to my question on the [Blender Python API Documentation](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bpy.types.KeyMaps.html?highlight=keymaps.new#bpy.types.KeyMaps.new)

My registration code now looks like this:

```
addon_keymaps = []
def register_keymaps():
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name = "Window",space_type='EMPTY', region_type='WINDOW')
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new("wm.call_menu_pie", type = "E",alt=True, value = "PRESS")
    kmi.properties.name = "editor_switcher_pie_menu"
    addon_keymaps.append(km)
```

You can find the final version of my addon on [GitHub](https://github.com/robert-trirop/editor_switcher)

[image]