# Add button to TOPBAR_MT_render

Tags: python, add-on

I want to add a button to the “TOPBAR_MT_render” menu (basically the menu in the top bar were you click to render.) The button should look like the Lock Interface one, so it should have a checkbox.

[image: Image which shows what I mean]

Would be nice if you could help me with this.

Comment: yeah i mean a BoolProperty then. I just want that the user can activate/deactivate a function of an addon.

Answer (score 1):

**Append or Prepend a draw method to menu class.**

Very closely related [How to add a checkbox to a pie menu?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43647/how-to-add-a-checkbox-to-a-pie-menu)

[image]

```
import bpy

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    scene = context.scene
    render = scene.render

    layout.prop(render, "use_lock_interface")

def register():
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_render.append(draw)

# make your unregister and remove draw
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

TIP Turn on developer extras in user preferences and can right click to  view source (Edit Source, as it opens in text editor.) of most UI elements.

[Add toggle hotkey to custom checkbox](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58486/add-toggle-hotkey-to-custom-checkbox)

Comment: Problem is, that I don't want it to be copied. I want a whole new Boolproperty. Which does other stuff then the "Lock Interface" one... Do you know how this works?

Comment: You're kidding? and Yes I know how this works. IMO this answers your question: ie how to add an item to render menu that looks like the lock interface. Bit tongue in cheek, I added a twin. There are numerous questions on how to create a boolean property on BSE.    The linked question if you even bothered to open it describes how to add a bool property.  Please make an effort to search for answers and not want more than you asked for., which becomes a problem.

Comment: Got it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Import bpy

class my_settings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    my_bool: bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name='Settings',
        default=True
    )



def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    rn_tool = context.scene.my_tool

    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(my_tool, "my_bool")


def register():
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_render.append(draw)
    bpy.utils.register_class(my_settings)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=my_settings)


def unregister():
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_render.remove(draw)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(my_settings)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Comment: Cool, do you mind adding any explanation? How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour