# Register Multiple Classes

Tags: python

I'm trying to register multiple classes at the same time like this:
I got it working like this

```
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PIE_SPECIALS)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SMART_BOOLEAN_ADD)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SMART_BOOLEAN_SUBTRACT)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SMART_BOOLEAN_SLICE)
```

But I want it to automatically register all classes in my file

Here is my attempt which isn't working yet:

```
classes = ('VIEW3D_PIE_SPECIALS','SMART_BOOLEAN_ADD','SMART_BOOLEAN_SUBTRACT','SMART_BOOLEAN_SLICE')


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        return 'bpy.utils.register_class('+(cls)+')'

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        return 'bpy.utils.unregister_class('+(cls)+')'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for register_module:

```
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
```

It grabs all the relevant classes in the file.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly.  One case I'm having trouble with though is registering multiple keymaps.  I have them all in one class, but they are not registering using this method (works if I register the class manually).  Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I know you'd have to register keymaps separately through register_keymaps(), but that's a bit outside my experience.  Perhaps this will be helpful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40755/how-to-register-keymaps-for-all-editor-types